# Do you need break in switch when return is used?

Tags: php

I was wondering if I need to use `break` in a `switch` function when `return` is used.

```
function test($string)
{
  switch($string)
  {
    case 'test1':
      return 'Test 1: ' . $string;
    case 'test2':
      return 'Test 2: ' . $string;
  }
}
```

I've tried it, and it works just fine without `break`. But is this safe?

Comment: what will happen if $string='testx';

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Yes, you can use `return` instead of `break`...

`break` is optional and is used to prevent "*falling*" through all the other `case` statements. So `return` can be used in a similar fashion, as `return` ends the function execution.

Also, if all of your `case` statements are like this:

```php
case 'foo':
   $result = find_result(...);
   break;
```

And after the `switch` statement you just have `return $result`, using `return find_result(...);` in each `case` will make your code much more readable.

Lastly, don't forget to add the `default` case. If you think your code will never reach the `default` case then you could use the [`assert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) function, because you can never be sure.

Answer (score 25):

You do not need a break, the return stops execution of the function.

(for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php says:

> If called from within a function, the return() statement immediately ends execution of the current function

)

Answer (score 7):

No its not necessary , because when the key word return is called it will indicate that the particular function which the switch/case was called has come to an end.

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need a `break` in a `switch case` statement. The `break` is actually optional, but use with caution.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need it, but I would strongly advise using it in any case as good practice.

Comment: no point, since return clearly exists by it self on execution =) Less code is better.

Comment: Less code != better. Go play code golf. I’d rather have readable, explicit code than code over-optimised just so it can be on one line at the expense of readability and understandability.

Comment: You can argue this both ways. Some compilers warn about non executable code after a return in a switch, some don't. It's personal preference, and for me at least it's colored by how many times I've been bitten by falling through a switch, I like to see the break.

Answer (score 3):

`return` gives the control back to the calling method, whereas `break` jumps to the first instruction after the switch block.

Answer (score 2):

Break is just a cautionary statement used to limit the control of switch stucture from going into another case...for example if you have three case statements and value is for first case and you have used case without any break structure then all the following cases will be executed inspite of the condition being satisfied only for the first case...
Return can perform the asme function so it won't be a problem if you use return in place of break because return will take control away from the switch case statement which is the need at that moment......
hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PHP 8 (Nov 2020), you can use match:

```
<?php

function test($string) {
   return match ($string) {
      'test1' => 'Test 1: ',
      'test2' => 'Test 2: '
   } . $string;
}
```

Although in this case you could just use an array:

```
<?php

function test($string) {
   return [
      'test1' => 'Test 1: ',
      'test2' => 'Test 2: '
   ][$string] . $string;
}
```

https://php.net/control-structures.match

Answer (score 0):

No. return jumps back directly to the function call returning the value after it and everything (in a function) that is after an executed return statement is ignored. So return itself can act as a break statement for functions and no further break is required. here is my example.

```
switch (ActiveSt)
            {
                case 0:
                    obj.Authuser(Session["UserId"].ToString());
                    obj.auditlog(UserID, MachineName, IpAdd, OsUser, Des, SysType, Screen, Fncname);
                    Session["UserId"] = null;
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('User authorized successfully');window.location ='frmUserPendingList.aspx';</script>");
                    return;
                case 7:
                    obj.Authuser(Session["UserId"].ToString());
                    obj.auditlog(IssueId, MachineName, IpAdd, OsUser, Des, SysType, Screen, Fncname);
                    Session["UserId"] = null;
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('User authorized successfully');window.location ='frmUserPendingList.aspx';</script>");
                    return;
                case 1:
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('User already authorized!');</script>");
                    errorHandle("User Already Authorized!");
                    return;
                case 5:
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('User already rejected!');</script>");
                    errorHandle("User already rejected!");
                    return;
            }
```