# Unreachalble break statements within a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, break

This code comes from w3resource.com PHP exercises (Arrays, #20):

```
<?php
function list_cmp($a, $b) { 
  global $order; 

  foreach($order as $key => $value) { 
      if($a==$value) { 
          return 0; 
          break; 
        } 

      if($b==$value) { 
          return 1; 
          break; 
        } 
    } 
} 

$order[0] = 1;
$order[1] = 3; 
$order[2] = 4; 
$order[3] = 2; 

$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 1; 
$array[2] = 3; 
$array[3] = 4; 
$array[4] = 2; 
$array[5] = 1; 
$array[6] = 2; 

usort($array, "list_cmp"); 

print_r($array); 
?>
```

I am using Netbeans and I am getting the info that both "break" statements are not reachable / cannot be reached. So the code is not correct? How can I correct it so it works the way it was inteded to work?

Thanks.

Comment: `return` leaves the function at that point, true. But i don't see `list_cmp()` being called.

Comment: Remove the breaks. `return` stops the execution of everything in the loop afterwards. So `break` will never be reached.

Comment: Think about how a `break` immediately after a `return` can be reached, then remove all the breaks that it applies to

Comment: @DrNachtschatten `list_cmp()` is the callback function used in `usort()`

Comment: @DrNachtschatten `usort($array, "list_cmp"); `

Comment: @DrNachtschatten - list_cmp is called within the usort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none code can be reached after `return` statement (that's why you getting that info). read more at [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) . in your case, you don't need `break` statement, because after `return` function will be finished anyway and leave loop as well, there's no point in to put `break`, you should just remove it.

see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330114/do-you-need-break-in-switch-when-return-is-used)