# Is this the right way doing this?

Tags: php, lookup-tables

I have this function where I input a couple of values. This is how I do it:

```
$alias = 11;
$row = ceil($alias / 8);
            switch ($row)
            {
                case 1:
                    return $alias + 10;
                case 2:
                    return $alias + 12;
                case 3:
                    return $alias + 14;
                case 4:
                    return $alias + 16;
                case 5:
                    return $alias + 18;
                case 6:
                    return $alias + 20;
                case 7:
                    return $alias + 22;
                default:

                break;
            }
```

I think there is a better way of doing this

Comment: dont you need break after every case?

Comment: Why not use return $alias + 10 + ($row-1)*2 ?

Comment: @AhmedAlhameli No you don't, since it's using `return` there's no need to `break` to skip the following cases

Comment: I found the almost the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330114/do-you-need-break-in-switch-when-return-is-used

Comment: use a math exp since it has a pattern i confirm what @Cris said .

Comment: It sure looks like a pattern, but what's the point of the code? What are the known rules? Should it do something for a value of `0`, or `8`?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“Is this the right way doing this?”_ is not a good question title.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with math.

```
return $alias + 10 + ((ceil($alias / 8)-1) * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully you discover there is a formula:

```php
$alias = 11;
$row = ceil($alias / 8);
switch ($row)
{
    case 1:
        return $alias + 10;//(1*2-2)+10 = 0+10 = 10
    case 2:
        return $alias + 12;//(2*2-2)+10 = (4-2)+10 = 2+10 = 12
    case 3:
        return $alias + 14;//(3*2-2)+10 = (6-2)+10 = 4+10 = 14
    case 4:
        return $alias + 16;//(4*2-2)+10 = (8-2)+10 = 6+10 = 16
    case 5:
        return $alias + 18;//.
    case 6:
        return $alias + 20;//..
    case 7:
        return $alias + 22;//(7*2-2)+10 = (14-2)+10 = 12+10 = 22
    default:

    break;
}
```

So follow the formula `($row*2-2)+10`, and then
Your switch will turn to a simple one expression:

```php
return $alias + ($row*2-2)+10;
```